# np.nan assigning massive negative integer?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run this code

```
import numpy as np

X = np.column_stack([np.arange(1,6), np.arange(1,6)])
X = np.roll(X,1,axis=0)
X[0,:] = np.nan
print(X)
```

My output is

```
array([[-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808],
       [                   1,                    1],
       [                   2,                    2],
       [                   3,                    3],
       [                   4,                    4]])
```

Which  I didn't think is what it's supposed to do... I also ran the code in colab to make sure something crazy wasn't going on with my machine. Am I doing something that doesn't make sense?

Expected output is something along the lines of

```
array([[NaN, NaN],
       [  1,   1],
       [  2,   2],
       [  3,   3],
       [  4,   4]])
```

Comment: Integers don't support NaN.

Comment: It gives an error for me @financial. Also are you running jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly You are getting this because you are using an old version of `numpy`

also you can't assign float numbers to integer as nan is of type 'float' and In the newer version `X[0,:] = np.nan` throw an errors:-`ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

So firstly use `astype()` method to convert your `int` array to `float`:-

```
X=X.astype(float)
```

Finally:-

```
X[0,:]=np.nan
```

Now if you print `X` you will get:-

```
array([[nan, nan],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.]])
```